# Windows Forms timer runs erratically

Tags: c#, winforms, timer, progress-bar

I'm attempting to control a progress bar via a timer - that is, have the progress bar advance 10% of its maximum for each timer_Tick.  The odd thing is that, while the progress bar does seem to advance with the timer_Tick, it appears that each tick comes in pairs (that is, I get a double-tick). Here's the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ExampleTestGUI
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();            
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;     //Set to false to prevent timer from auto-starting.
            timer1.Interval = 1000;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 10;
        }

        // COMBO BOX
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        // START BUTTON
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            button1.Text = "CANCEL TEST";
            comboBox1.Enabled = false;
            timer1.Start();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (progressBar1.Value != 10)
            {
                progressBar1.Value++;
            }
            else
            {
                timer1.Stop();
                button1.Text = "START AGAIN";
                comboBox1.Enabled = true;
                progressBar1.Value = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`timer1.Start` is only dependent on the `button1_Click`.  Has anyone experienced this odd behavior before?  Is there a rookie mistake in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the handler only once.  move this line to the form's constructor:

```
timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(timer1_Tick);
```

or if you have the tick event already created using the designer, then remove the line entirely.

Comment: This was my gut reaction as well. Probably has it hooked up in the designer as well as the button1_Click handler.

Comment: Let me add an extra nugget of info I learned for future newbies:  

I found that LarsTech's solution worked, as long as I didn't button1_Click a second time, or a third, or a fourth, etc... subsequent button1_Clicks resulted in the same odd timer behavior, usually increasing the number of ticks with each click.  

The problem was that I failed to unsubscribe from the timer1_Tick event handler, so subsequent button1_Clicks just added an extra subscription to the timer1_Tick event, rather than overriding it.  Adding an unsubscribe line after timer1.Stop resolved this secondary problem.

Comment: @blockheadjr You don't have to unsubscribe the event though.  Setting it once in the constructor or in the designer is good enough.  After that, stopping the timer stops the event from firing.

Comment: I found that each time I invoked timer1.Stop then timer1.Start again, the timer increased the number of ticks occuring each second (e.g. second start = two ticks at a time, third start = three ticks at a time, fourth start = four ticks at a time, etc). It became clear there was stackup occuring.  The only way to "reset" was to close out the program and start fresh. Unsubscribing resolved that issue.

Comment: @blockheadjr Then you are always adding the handler.  Don't do that.  Just comment out the line.

Comment: But it's the only handler I've got! =)  If stopping the timer stops the event from firing, then I shouldn't run into this stackup, correct?  And yet stackup is what I'm getting; this suggests to me that though the timer has been stopped, I'm still subscribed to the event.  If stopping the timer is supposed to be equivalent to unsubscribing to the event, my version of Visual Studio isn't behaving that way.

Comment: @blockheadjr You would have to post your project somewhere where I can download it and look for you.

Comment: No need.  The solution I have, though maybe not elegant, does the trick.  Thanks for your help, LarsTech.